# Looking for opinions on Virtual Web Appliances

Tags: security, web, webfilter

My client is looking for some web filtering devices and I'm looking for some recommendations for virtual appliances.  Anyone got any thoughts?

Comment: Do you have any more detailed requirements or goals?

Comment: Testing the waters.  The client wants to prevent users from accessing social networking/streaming sites.  Something affordable.  We're looking to use a virtual appliance and am just looking to see what everyone out there is using and their opinions on it.

Comment: OK - then what's the expected budget or range?

Comment: Sorry.  100-200 users and I'll be re-selling it to the client.   I'm thinking approximately $5000 range max.

Answer (score 0):

Vyatta is an open-source firewall that can be deployed as a virtual device.  I haven't had a chance to play with it, but I've been meaning to try it out in my development environment.